# Get errno in class __exit__

Tags: python, exception, contextmanager

I have a class that creates a backup of the current directory in `__init__`, and restores the backup if anything went wrong. I thought that would be a great job for a context manager to handle:

```
class Directory:
    def __init__(self):
        self._create_backup()

    ...

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exit_type, exit_value, exit_traceback):
        if exit_type is KeyboardInterrupt:
            self._restore_from_backup()
            sys.exit("Caught system interrupt. Aborting.")
            # This is actually more complicated, but for the sake of MCVE

        # Handle other exceptions here

        else:
            self._delete_backup()
```

Now, I want to get the `errno` attribute of the exception, to check if it matches `errno.EPERM`, but I can't figure out how.

I'd prefer not to use hacky solutions like regex matches on `exit_value`.

Comment: Have you tried to print the exit type for debugging? Then you could see what object type it is. also, you probably should use `isinstance(exit_type, KeyboardInterrupt)`.

Comment: Yes, I have, but I want to make a distinction between different kinds of `OSError`s. Note that `exit_type` isn't an exception instance, but a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit_value` is the instance of the class `exc_type`.  You should be able to do something like the following:

```
if isinstance(exit_value, OSError):
    print(exit_value.errno)
```

You can also do something like the following if you want to catch other exceptions that happen to define `errno`:

```
errno = getattr(exit_value, 'errno', None)
if errno is not None:
    print(errno)
```

I would probably use the latter since any exception defining an attribute named `errno` can probably be compared against the `errno.E*` constants.

Answer (score 1):

`IOError` instance has attribute `errno`, so you want something like:

```
def __exit__(self, exit_type, exit_value, exit_traceback):
    if exit_type is KeyboardInterrupt:
        self._restore_from_backup()
        sys.exit("Caught system interrupt. Aborting.")
        # This is actually more complicated, but for the sake of MCVE
    elif exit_type is IOError:
        if exit_value.errno == errno.EPERM:
            # Handle your desired case
    # Handle other exceptions here

    else:
        self._delete_backup()
```

**EDIT:** I assume OP imports `errno` since he mentions using it in the question but of course the following line is required on before `errno` module can be used

```
import errno
```

Comment: Don't forget the `import errno`

Comment: OP for sure imported `errno` as he mentions checking against `errno.EPERM` but I will add it to my answer @MatiasCicero